# jQuery LazyLoad for Assets images

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, jquery, ce-image

I have an EE site that is using Assets to display large images (1080px wide) that stack vertically.  I would love to use this [LazyLoad jQuery script](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), however it is required to change the "src=" in the  tag to "data-original="

In my EE install, I am using Assets to manage these images along with CE Image to resize.  In my template, I have this Assets tag pair to output the images.  I would wish to keep the CE Image single tag, only because I want it to output both the width (which should stay at 1080px), and variable height using "add_dims=" parameter.

```
{gallery_items var_prefix="file"}
  {exp:ce_img:single src="{file:url}" alt="{file:alt_text}" max_width="1080" itemprop="image" add_dims="yes" class="lazyload"}
{/gallery_items}
```

If I simply change out the "src=", nothing seems to output. Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [pair tag](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics) for this:

```
{gallery_items var_prefix="file"}
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{file:url}" max_width="1080" itemprop="image"}
<img data-original="{made_url}" class="lazyload" alt="{file:alt_text}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/gallery_items}
```

Comment: OK! Thanks for that. We're getting closer, however I'm still not seeing the images.  What I do see are the image tags being outputted now. For some reason the images aren't being rendered on the page.  This may be a separate issue though.. unless you think otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, here's the output `<img
data-original="//d2omqnuzo0t1t8.cloudfront.net/images/remote/http_s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxx/gallery/don-carlos/don-xxxxxxxxxx.jpg" class="lazyload" alt="" width="1080" height="720" />`

Comment: data-original="{made_url}", but if u use as3 - data-original="{aws_url}"

Comment: Found the issue, which was javascript related as I was suspecting.  Thank you! Works great now!